# Singleton and thread safety

Tags: concurrency, thread-safety, singleton

When talking about Singletons and threadsafe-ty issues concerning race conditions in creating the singleton instance, which thread are we talking about?

Using this as example, assume I have a MyApp that uses a Singleton

```
class MyApp
{
    MySingleton oneAndOnly;

    int main() // application entry point
    {
        oneAndOnly = MySingleton::GetInstance();
    }

    void SpawnThreads()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
              Thread spawn = new Thread(new ThreadStart(JustDoIt));
              spawn.Start();
        }
    }

    void JustDoIt()
    {
        WaitRandomAmountOfTime(); // Wait to induce race condition (maybe?) for next line.

        MySingleton localInstance = MySingleton::GetInstance();
        localInstance.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is it talking about:

- when I open the MyApp.exe once, and
  then once more again, trying to have
  both opened?
- Or is it talking about the threads spawned by MyApp? What if MyApp does
  not spawn threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows [threads exist solely within the scope of a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), i.e. the running instance of an application. So [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) means making sure that **shared resources are accessed sequentially from multiple threads within a given process**.

In more general terms, **race conditions occur as a result of concurrency regardless of scope**. For example a distributed application that exposes a shared resource to external processes, is still subject to race conditions if access to that resource isn't properly regulated.